# user32 MoveWindow doesnt work in C#, windows 7, console application

Tags: c#, window, console-application, user32

I am not a windows developer at all (i do AS3 stuff), but i wrote this C# console application in visual c# 2010 in order to test something.
The app should take an open window and resize and reposition it.

i open a blank Chrome window (titled "Untitled"), but the functions controlling the window don't work (even though debugger stops on them - meaning the app did find the right window).

any ideas why?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {


        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

       [DllImport("user32.dll")]
       private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process proc in processlist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle) && proc.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled")
                {
                   ShowWindow(proc.Handle, 3);
                   MoveWindow(proc.Handle, 0, 0, 100, 100, true);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   MoveWindow(proc.Handle, ...);
```

proc.Handle is not what you think it is.  It is the *process* handle, not the Process.MainWindowHandle that you are interested in.

You are asking this question because you don't check for errors.  So you don't know why it doesn't work.  These functions return *bool*, false means that you got it wrong.  Throw a Win32Exception so this isn't completely undiagnosable:

```
if (!MoveWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, ...)) {
    throw new Win32Exception();
}
```